# Bad JSON in X-Dropbox-Metadata header

Tags: java, json, exception, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox JAVA SDK version 1.8.1 for my app. Recently, I face the following error while downloading files using downloading API:
**Bad JSON in X-Dropbox-Metadata header: 1.96: \"photo_info\": expecting the end of an object (\"}\")"**.
I haven't requested any media info neither did I set *includeMediaInfo* to *true*.
Here is the code snippet:

```
DbxClient.Downloader downloader = client.startGetFile(folderPath+"/"+filename,"");
InputStream in = downloader.body;
OutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
byte buf[] = new byte[10000000];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf, 0, 10000000)) != -1) {
 outs.write(buf, 0, len);
}
outs.close();
outs.flush();
in.close();
downloader.close();
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
threw exception [com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadResponse: Bad JSON in X-Dropbox-Metadata header: 1.96: ""photo_info"": expecting the end of an object (""}"")] with root cause" "com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReadException: 1.96: ""photo_info"": expecting the end of an object (""}"")
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.expectObjectEnd(JsonReader.java:82)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry$File$PhotoInfo$1.read(DbxEntry.java:412)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry$File$PhotoInfo$1.read(DbxEntry.java:393)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry$PendingReader.read(DbxEntry.java:957)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.readField(JsonReader.java:30)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry._read(DbxEntry.java:880)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry.read(DbxEntry.java:826)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry$File$1.read(DbxEntry.java:315)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry$File$1.read(DbxEntry.java:310)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.readFully(JsonReader.java:386)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.readFully(JsonReader.java:292)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.startGetSomething(DbxClient.java:472)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.startGetFile(DbxClient.java:452)
```

The similar kind of exception also occurs with searchAPI.
The same code snippet was working fine in the previous version 1.7.7  and I was able to download files.

Please help me figure out this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the report. We (Dropbox) are investigating.

Comment: See https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204278796-com-dropbox-core-json-JsonReadException. This is fixed in SDK 1.8.2.

Comment: Thanks for the update!